# SEO Lite & Home Page

Tags: seo-lite

I have implemented SEO Lite into my site and have it all set up and working for all of my pages/entries, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to get it to work for my home page.

I am using {exp:seo_lite use_last_segment='yes’} in my main layout template. Since the home page has no segment, the tag is not pulling in the home page channel entry values from the SEO Lite tab.

How can I get this working?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out. In my main layout I used the following, where the entry ID of 11 is the ID for the home page entry:

```
{if segment_1 ==""}
{exp:seo_lite entry_id="11"}
{if:else}
{exp:seo_lite use_last_segment='yes'}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yepp, the homepage is a special case as it does not have an url_title which you need if you use the "use_last_segment" parameter. So you'll have to fetch it using entry_id, **or alternatively** modify the default SEO Lite template in the CP to fit the homepage.